# setRetainInstance not retaining the instance

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm trying to use setRetainInstance() but it seems not working for me! =(.
I simplified the problem to the easiest version:

I have a fragment with a TextView and a Button.

The initial text of the TextView is "I'm waiting" when the button is pressed the text changes to "Hello!"

That is my code:

**The fragment:**

```
public class SayHelloFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.say_hello_layout, container);
        final TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        view.findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                text.setText("Hello!");

            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

}
```

**The Activity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

}
```

**The activity's layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/say_hello_fragment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    class="com.example.retaintext.SayHelloFragment" />
```

**The Fragment's layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="I&apos;m Waiting"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

But when I play it, press the button and change the device's orientation the text becomes reset.

What am I missing? How can I solve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are missing that `onCreateView` runs after the rotation again and inflates the default view with the default text again.

You need to restore the state of your views manually, e.g.:

```
public class SayHelloFragment extends Fragment {

    private String mText;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.say_hello_layout, container);
        final TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        if (mText != null)
            text.setText(mText);

        view.findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mText = "Hello!";
                text.setText(mText);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: This answer was very useful. I wasn't aware that onRetainInstance saves the Fragment object, but I still have to rebuild UI in onCreateView.